# Running Hive or Spark using Amazon EMR on Talend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, talend

I am trying to run hive queries on Amazon AWS using Talend. So far I can create clusters on AWS using the ***tAmazonEMRManage*** object, the next steps would be 
1) To load the tables with data
2) Run queries against the Tables.

My data sits in S3. So far the documentation on talend does not seem to indicate the Hive objects ***tHiveLoad*** and ***tHiveRow*** support S3 which makes me wonder whether running hive queries on EMR via Talend is even possible

The documentation on how to do this is scarce. Has anyone tried doing this successfully or can point me in the right direction please?

Comment: more detail....

Comment: http://garpitmzn.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/talend-insert-data-from-s3-to-aws.html

Comment: that wasn't what i asked for